# Tactics Ogre - Do guests use consumables?

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp

Still in chapter 1 and I gave Catiua Field Alchemy 1 because I figured being a Priest, and a primary healer, she should be able to heal with bigger med leaves. Will she even use the med leaves, or any consumables? Did I just waste the skill points?